# Why overriding Equals method is not required?

Tags: c#

As we know everything in C# is derived from Object which has the `Equals` method and few more.

I was creating a class and I found that I don’t have to use the `override` keyword with the `Equals` method. I am not sure why?

```
public class Employee //: IEquatable<Employee>
{
    public int Emp_Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Emp_name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Dept_name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool Equals(Employee other)  //here it should use override 
    {
        return this.Emp_Id.Equals(other.Emp_Id);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Emp_Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can override - `public override bool Equals(object obj)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're not overriding `Equals(object)`.  You're creating an *overload* of the `Equals` method because of the different type.

Comment: Yes, this results in having the two methods `bool Equals(object obj)` and `bool Equals(Employee other)`.